# Comma in Elasticsearch synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch

Some of the sentences I want to define as syonyms have commas in them, for example:

"Employment Information" and "Your Activity, Your Job" are synonyms.

However if I define them in the following way the result is not what I envisioned, since "," has a special meaning in the Elasticsearch format:

Employment Information=>Your Activity, Your Job

Is the only solution for me to use WordNet synonym format in this case or perhaps I can just ignore the comma entirely and take it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think `comma` will be an issue, If you are using `standard analyzer` then it will remove `comma`. This is my test setup

```
"filter": {
     "my_synonym_filter": {
         "type": "synonym",
         "synonyms": [
             "employment information=>your activity your job"
         ]
     }
 },
 "analyzer": {
     "my_synonyms": {
         "tokenizer": "standard",
         "filter": [
             "lowercase",
             "my_synonym_filter"
         ]
     }
 }
```

It is good to use `lowercase filter` to avoid case sensitive [issues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms-analysis-chain.html), so now this query

```
GET my_index/_analyze?text=employment Information&analyzer=my_synonyms
```

will give you following tokens

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "your",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "activity",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 22,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "your",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 22,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "job",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 22,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

There is a [gotcha](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html) with `multiword synonym`, if you analyze the output of
`GET my_index/_analyze?text=employment Information is useful&analyzer=my_synonyms`, you will get unexpected results like this

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "your",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "activity",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 22,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "is",
         "start_offset": 23,
         "end_offset": 25,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "your",
         "start_offset": 23,
         "end_offset": 25,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "useful",
         "start_offset": 26,
         "end_offset": 32,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "job",
         "start_offset": 26,
         "end_offset": 32,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

You can solve this issue with [simple contraction](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms-expand-or-contract.html#synonyms-contraction), write `synonyms` like this

```
"synonyms": [
     "employment information,your activity your job=>sentence1"
 ]
```

If you are using `keyword analyzer` then you could use `pattern replace char filter` to remove comma.